# How to take complements in sub-$\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory

If I have a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ over $X$ and I have some sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$, is $X\in\mathcal{B}$? What's the usual definition? I have two seemingly contradicting texts (one set in probability theory, the other in pure measure theory). Thanks!

Comment: What do the two texts say? You must have $\emptyset \in \mathcal{B}$ and $\emptyset^C \in \mathcal{B}$

Comment: One (without having the defined the notion of sub-$\sigma$-algebra) continuously speaks of $(X,\mathcal{B})$ as a measurable space after only having claimed $\mathcal{B}$ to be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{A}$; the other defined the notion as applicable whenever $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{A}$. @Henry

Comment: Yes, you are right, but my very next thought was the title of this question.

Comment: It would be helpful for you to give the definitions you're referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $X$, a subset $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{A}$ is a $\textbf{sub-algebra}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ if $\mathcal{B}$ is also a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$, i.e. $\emptyset \in \mathcal{B}$, $X \in \mathcal{B}$, and $\mathcal{B}$ is closed under complements and countable unions.

Some points to help think it through: if they call $(X, \mathcal{B})$ a measurable space, this can only mean $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-alg. over $X$; also, remember that to define a $\sigma$-alg., you need to specify what set it is a $\sigma$-alg. over -- if they call $\mathcal{B}$ a sub-algebra of $\mathcal{A}$ without specifying what set $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-alg. over, it is natural to conclude that it is over $X$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I don‘t agree with you claiming it would be natural to assume the $\sigma$ algebra be over $X$... also, the underlying set always falls off as the biggest (natural order) element of the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: In the end I hoped for an answer that said something like it would be standard to assume $X\in\mathcal{B}$ in probability theory... but I guess this specific question is rather individual to authors.

Comment: You're welcome. I believe that the first time I ran into the definition of a sub-algebra I had similar thoughts to yours, and ended up realizing sometime later on, in the context of Hilbert spaces of functions defined on these measure spaces, that it is only natural for $X \in \mathcal{B}$.

Comment: It's natural in this setting because then a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ that is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ will also be measurable with respect to $\mathcal{A}$, where here $Y$ is also a measure space.